# How can I get only heading names.from the text file

Tags: python, nlp, jnlp, text-extraction

I have a Text file as below:

```
Education: 

askdjbnakjfbuisbrkjsbvxcnbvfiuregifuksbkvjb.iasgiufdsegiyvskjdfbsldfgd

Technical skills : 
 java,j2ee etc.,

work done: 

oaugafiuadgkfjwgeuyrfvskjdfviysdvfhsdf,aviysdvwuyevfahjvshgcsvdfs,bvisdhvfhjsvjdfvshjdvhfjvxjhfvhjsdbvfkjsbdkfg
```

I would like to extract only the heading names such as Education,Technical Skills etc.

the code is  :

```
with open("aks.txt") as infile, open("fffm",'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Technical Skills":
            copy =True
        elif line.strip() == "Workdone":
            copy = True


        elif line.strip() ==  "Education":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
        fh = open("fffm.txt", 'r')
        contents = fh.read()
        len(contents)
```

Comment: your lines have `:` chars in the end of them. `.strip` does not strip `:` characters so that may run into problems

Answer (score 0):

To get just the headings from your text file, you could use the follows:

```
import re

with open('aks.txt') as f_input:
    headings = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*:', f_input.read())
    print headings
```

This would display the following:

```
['Education', 'Technical skills', 'work done']
```

Comment: Thanks for d answer but how can I get only title names.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your expected output, this would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the title names occure before a colon (:) then you can write a regex to search for such a pattern.

```
    import re
    with open("aks.txt") as infile:
      for s in re.finditer(r'(?<=\n).*?(?=:)',infile.read()):
        print s.group()
```

The output will be like

```
   Education
   Technical skills 
   work done
```